# Kibana show no results for geohash aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I'd like to show my dataset on tile map. I'm using kibana 4.1.1.
My data is set like this:

```
{
  "_index": "business-data",
  "_type": "users",
  "_id": "AVkRMFztZOUsFUpKvZ-0",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "first_name": "Nessa",
    "gender": "female",
    "location": {
      "lat": 48.8668481401949,
      "lon": 2.19256871957155
    }
  }
}
```

The mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "first_name": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "gender": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_point"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Location is a valid geo_point.

[image: geo_point.png]

The tile map is shown when the visualisation is being created, but "No result" when the basic geohash aggregation bu location field is requested.

[image: Capture d’écran 2016-12-18 à 10.28.46.png]

giving:

[image: Capture d’écran 2016-12-18 à 10.31.12.png]

Comment: peter - Can you post the above kibana request ?

Comment: Hi,above the search text box in kibana, you can choose range time, by default kibana choose the last 15 min,because of that you can see any result

Comment: Hi! My index has doesn't show this option, as it doesn't contains time-based events.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with you advice, thanks. Anyways, the kibana index is not event based in my case.

New mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "user": {
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
        },
        "user_id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "first_name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "gender": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```